# Finding DNS server IP address using sockets?

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I have an embedded WiFi (no OS). Most of the time, the built in DNS resolver works perfectly. But there are some cases where these function fail to work properly. When failure occurs, builtin functions fail to resolve and report the IP for any DNS servers, so they are useless.

I need to know how I can obtain the IP addresses of the DNS server using some socket (raw, udp, tcp). Forgive me, but I do not know how to do this and have not found it through google.

Everything I have found assumes some OS and terminal usage, neither of which are available in my environment. Also, The built in functions will have already obtained an IP address by this point using DHCP.

Comment: Are you talking about implementing your own DNS resolver? It can be done but it's a pretty big pain in the ass. The RFC docs can be found here but you're better off looking for a library that can implement it for you: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt

Comment: The problem is getting the IP addresses of the DNS servers. The built-in module to resolve works, and when it doen't it is because it failed to get the IPs of the DNS servers when connecting. If I can get the IPs somehow (programmatically), then the I can configure the built-in DNS modules using them. In the testing environment, I just open my laptop and retrieve the IPs using ipconfig -all then manually configure the device, but I need this to be fully implemented in the device so it can happen without user interaction.